# What can't be done with a neural network

Tags: complexity-theory, artificial-intelligence, neural-networks

[This](ftp://ftp.sas.com/pub/neural/FAQ.html#A_cando) reference from the german wikipedia article on neural networks states:

> There are also many other important problems that are so difficult that a neural network will be unable to learn them without memorizing the entire training set, such as:
>
> - Predicting random or pseudo-random numbers.
> - Factoring large integers.
> - Determining whether a large integer is prime or composite.
> - Decrypting anything encrypted by a good algorithm.

**Can someone explain, why this limitation should hold for all kinds of neural networks and for any advances in the future?**

**Are there any formal possibilities to prove that this problems cant be solved with a neural network?**

Lets look at the third note. There are many insights on the distribution of prime numbers and [this paper](https://www.cse.iitk.ac.in/users/manindra/algebra/primality_v6.pdf) shows, that the calculations for proving that an integer is a prime number, can be done in polynomial time (PRIMES is in P). So why is this problem "to difficult" to be solved by a neural network?

Comment: Neural networks solve problems in a very specific way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This paper](http://research.cs.queensu.ca/~akl/cisc879/papers/SELECTED_PAPERS_FROM_VARIOUS_SOURCES/05070215382317071.pdf) introduces a finite size neural network and proves that it can simulate a Turing Machine, meaning that this NN is Turing complete. Thus anything that may be computed using TMs can be computed by this type of NNs. You may want to read [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1410.5401.pdf%20(http://Neural%20Turning%20Machines)) too.

Comment: Note that the problems listed in the question are (thought to be) hard for TMs. Except for primality checking, that is.

Comment: @adrianN I am curious, too, If there is a NN more powerful than TMs.

Comment: Probably not, Church-Turing thesis and all that.

Comment: @adrianN, probably, he asked if deterministic NN can solve harder (than $\mathsf P$) problems in polynomial amount of resources. But I don't think so.

Comment: I don't think that construction provides an entirely fair way to answer this question with "they can compute anything computable", because it requires a very a-typical use of the NNs.

Comment: Wait, does this paper claim that NN of size $O(1)$ can solve any problem in $\mathsf {PR}$?

Comment: This answer talks about the expressive power of NN, I think a good answer should talk about the learning perspective, though to do this you need to have a well defined learning task at hand.  See e.g this question https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/15039/why-can-machine-learning-not-recognize-prime-numbers

Comment: Why do you use NN to mean RNN (recurrent) ? Even the training algorithm is not quite exactly the same